# Merging two files in Unix to selectively print columns from both files based on Key Column

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have two text files:

File1 - ConnectionID,Host,IP
File2 - ConnectionID,DestType,DestName,Counts

I would like to print matching ConnectionID from both files as
ConnectionID,Host,IP,DestType,DestName,Count and also spit the unmatched lines separately from both files.

Example Data:

File 1 : four Lines

```
1,serverA,1.1.1.1
2,ServerA,1.1.1.1
3,ServerB,1.1.1.2
4,ServerC,1.1.1.3
```

File 2: Three lines

```
1,Q,Dest1,10
3,T,Dest2,20
5,T,Dest3,45
```

Output wanted as:

```
1,ServerA,1.1.1.1,Q,Dest1,10
3,ServerB,1.1.1.2,T,Dest2,20
2,ServerA,1.1.1.1,null,null,null
4,ServerC,1.1.1.3,null,null,null
5,null,null,T,Dest3,45
```

I wanted Unix commands using awk, Perl, sed etc.

This is like in databases:

```
select columns from table a, table b where a.ConnectionID=b.ConnectionID
```

also inner join and outer join
all results as output

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. Makes it much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

The [join](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html) program is meant for just this sort of thing. It's not a coincidence that it shares a name with the SQL operator.

```
join -t, -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.2,2.3,2.4 -a1 -a2 -e null file1 file2
```

should do the trick. Just note that both files should be sorted on the first column like your sample ones are.